# Can't open image on mac with OpenCV

Tags: python, macos, opencv

I am trying to open an image with OpenCV on mac with Python with this simple program:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
img = cv2.imread("image.jpg", 1)
cv2.imshow("image", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

But every time I run it I get this error:

```
   cv2.imshow("image", img)
   error: /Users/travis/build/skvark/opencv-
   python/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:325: error: (-215) 
   size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function imshow
```

I have researched this question but it says that the image may be empty, but I'm pretty sure my image isn't empty as I can open it and look at it.

Comment: What is your opencv and python versions.?

Comment: Your code is working for me just fine in windows. Most of the time the cause is a problem in reading the image, can you change the image and re-test if you are sure that the path is correct (respecting slashes/back-slashes)

Comment: I too recommend changing the image path. I tried with empty image to get same error. I fixed the path and everything was fine

Comment: Haha, my path was wrong, I started with Macintosh HD/ and continued the path, but I actually just needed to start with /Users/. And then continue the path, anyways thank you everyone!

Comment: I have voted to close as the problem "was due to a simple/typographical error." Glad you got it working though!

Answer (score 2):

I have faced same problem couple of days and I solved my problem by giving full path of image in cv2.imread()

here's a sample

```
import cv2
import os

img = cv2.imread(os.path.expanduser( "~/Downloads/Pics/A.jpg"))
cv2.namedWindow("Images")
cv2.imshow('Images',img)
cv2.waitKey(1)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```